# How to create a list of linear models in R?

Tags: r, list, lm

I need to create a named list of linear models in R.

```
models=list()
for (tag in tagnames){
   expr=paste0(tag," ~ .")
   f=formula(expr)
   models[tag]=lm(f,df)
 }
```

This is the code that I wrote; it actually creates the list, but apparently it is a list of lists which are not callable objects (i.e., the method predict doesn't work on the elements of the list).

How can I make the element of the lists usable as actual lm objects?

Comment: Could you give an example for `tagnames`?

Comment: tagname is a list of strings, containing the names of the columns of df.

Comment: this should be in double brackets as it is a list:
models[[tag]] = lm(f,df)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a list of your models with `lapply`:

```
models <- lapply(tagnames, function(x) lm(formula(paste0(x, " ~ .")), df))
```

and assign the names with

```
names(models) <- tagnames
```

Then call `predict` on the list element:

```
predict(models[["name"]])
```

Comment: also use `reformulate`: `models <- lapply(tagnames, function(x) lm(reformulate(".", x), df))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can this:

```
models[[tag]]=lm(f,df)


models=list()
tagnames <- names(cars)
for (tag in tagnames){
  expr=paste0(tag," ~ .")
  f=formula(expr)
  fit <- lm( f, data = cars)
  models[[tag]]=fit
}
```